# Organizing a large python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been working on a general utility script for a while now that basically just accepts user input to preform some task like opening a program. In this program, I define a name "command" as a raw_input and then use if statements to check the list for a command (small example below).

Constantly using if statements is making the program run slowly and so I'm wondering if there is a better way such as maybe a table of commands? I'm pretty new to programming so not sure how to accomplish this.

```
import os
command = raw_input('What would you like to open:')

if 'skype' in command:
    os.chdir('C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone')
    os.startfile('Skype.exe')
```

Comment: I doubt the `if` statements are making the command run slowly. Checking if a substring is in a string is pretty fast. You likely have another problem.

Comment: tons of if statements will make your code really un-maintainable and hard to read. so it's a good idea to get rid of them. but agf's right, it's probably not the cause of the slowness.

Comment: Yea, an if statement has minimal impact on performance. You would need a lot of them for it to have an impact.

Comment: Does executing your script now with something like 'skype notepad firefox' start three different processes or just one?

Comment: Good question Josh. If it does, and you go with my solution you could split the string and loop the if statement.

Comment: Wow, this is great! It does start three different processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can keep the commands in a dictionary with a tuple, and do something like this to store the commands.

```
command = {}
command['skype'] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone', 'Skype.exe'
command['explorer'] = 'C:\Windows\', 'Explorer.exe'
```

You could then do the following to execute the correct command based on the user input.

```
if raw_input.lower().strip() in command: # Check to see if input is defined in the dictionary.
   os.chdir(command[raw_input][0]) # Gets Tuple item 0 (e.g. C:\Program Files.....)
   os.startfile(command[myIraw_inputput][1]) # Gets Tuple item 1 (e.g. Skype.exe)
```

You can find more information on `Dictionaries` and `Tuples` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

In case you need to allow multiple commands, you can separate them by a space and [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the commands into an array.

```
for input in raw_input.split():
    if input.lower().strip() in command: # Check to see if input is defined in the dictionary.
       os.chdir(command[input][0]) # Gets Tuple item 0 (e.g. C:\Program Files.....)
       os.startfile(command[input][4]) # Gets Tuple item 1 (e.g. Skype.exe)
```

This would allow you to issue commands like `skype explorer`, but keep in mind that there are no room for typos, so they need to be an exact match, separated with nothing but white-spaces. As an example you could write `explorer`, but not `explorer!`.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Is `command` the command or a list of commands? That's not valid Python, it doesn't get rid of the `if` statements, all you've done is make it less clear what is going on by moving some strings out of context without indicating what they represent.

Comment: Command would be a dictionary. It would remove the need for a massive amount of if statements, and cut it down to a single. You can then load the data from a alternative data-source, or define it directly in code.

Comment: `if 'skype' in command` where `command` is a dictionary doesn't test the same thing as `if 'skype' in command` if command is a string.

Comment: I tried it out on my computer and works fine. I am no python expert, but I don't see why this would fail, as long as the input is identical. Just make sure to convert it to lower case.

Comment: It depends on if OP cares about the entered input being allowed to be a substring of the intended command. If not, this answer is fine. If so, he would need a loop.

Comment: Yep, exactly. I mentioned that in the comment on the questions, but can easily be fixed by a split and loop as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've started testing out with this solution and it looks great.