# Can I open an application from a script during runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was wondering if i could open any kind of application in Python during runtime?

Comment: I assume that you are asking how to run application from Python. There are few limitations, if any on the kind of application you can execute from Python, but your question is simply to vague.

Comment: This answer might interest you as well, if you want to start custom applications at run-time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026316/organizing-a-large-python-script2-7/14026342#14026342

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Windows you would use one of the following commands like this.

[subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('C:\\myprogram.exe')
```

[os.startfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

```
import os
os.startfile('C:\\myprogram.exe')
```

Answer (score 4):

Using system you can also take advantage of open function (especially if you are using mac os/unix environment. Can be useful when you are facing permission issue.

```
import os

path = "/Applications/Safari.app"
os.system(f"open {path}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try having a look at `subprocess.call` http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Just import `import subprocess` and invoke `subprocess.call('applicaitonName')`.

For example you want to open VS Code in **Ubuntu**:

```
import subprocess
cmd='code';
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

This line can be also used to open application, if you need to have more information, e.g. as I want to capture error so I used **stderr**

```
subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some extra examples for Windows, Linux and MacOS:

```py
import subprocess

# Generic: open explicitly via executable path
subprocess.call(('/usr/bin/vim', '/etc/hosts'))
subprocess.call(('/System/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit', '/etc/hosts'))

# Linux: open with default app registered for file
subprocess.call(('xdg-open', '/tmp/myfile.html'))

# Windows: open with whatever app is registered for the given extension
subprocess.call(('start', '/tmp/myfile.html'))

# Mac: open with whatever app is registered for the given extension
subprocess.call(('open', '/tmp/myfile.html'))

# Mac: open via MacOS app name
subprocess.call(('open', '-a', 'TextEdit', '/etc/hosts'))

# Mac: open via MacOS app bundle name
subprocess.call(('open', '-b', 'com.apple.TextEdit', '/etc/hosts'))
```

If you need to open specifically HTML pages or URLs, then there is the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module:

```py
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('file:///tmp/myfile.html')

webbrowser.open('https://yahoo.com')

# force a specific browser
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('file:///tmp/myfile.html')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the this code : -

```
 import subprocess
 subprocess.call('drive:\\programe.exe')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
import os
import subprocess

command  = r"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\file_name.exe"
os.system(command)
#subprocess.Popen(command)
```