# How do I open an application using Python

Tags: python

How do I open an app like Minecraft using os or subprocess? I went through a few videos and none of them worked. Do I just use the name of the app or its location?

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: There are many existing resources, include the Python's own documentation that address what you want to know, so there's no reason to ask such a general question here on SO IMO — and apparently you have done little or no research of your own.

Comment: Follow this. There are given answers for Linux and Windows.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831716/can-i-open-an-application-using-python-during-run-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example, you could use:

```
subprocess.run(r'"C:\path_to_minecraft\minecraft"',shell=True)
```

Or if you have Windows shortcuts you add the .lnk extension in the call:

```
subprocess.run(r'"C:\path_to_minecraft\minecraft.lnk"',shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

this works.

```
import os
os.system("your app.exe")
```