# control vpn from python running on native windows

Tags: python, windows, vpn

Can a python script running in windows turn the VPN on and off programmatically.

My script alternates reading from a database which requires the VPN on and another source which requires it be off

Using jupyter-lab. WSL is not an option due to VPN conflict

Comment: You could use `subprocess.call` to run `rasdial.exe` which is a command line tool to connect or disconnect from a vpn. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831716/can-i-open-an-application-from-a-script-during-runtime   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/ff859533(v=ws.11)   Windows only solution.